# ISSUE Nuget restore of sitecore.myget.org

Tags: nuget

Today when I try to call NuGet to restore from gulp files for

1) `https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json` is asking for credentials, which was working fine till yesterday. When I google I could see it has been moved to 2) `https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-packages`
But there is no feed URL same as `index.json`. Could you please help?
Jenkins build is blocked as the URL is not accessible without username password.

I used the above 1) URL in IE and it loaded but in new windows, it asks for user name password.
Does anyone know how to get the feed of new URL  2) above

#### Update:

I have updated to Nuget 5.4.0 but now I'm getting an error

```
sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages: Package 'Sitecore.NVelocity.9.0.0' is not found on source 'sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages'. 
sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages: Package 'Sitecore.Zip.12.0.0' is not found on source 'sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages'. 
sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages: Package 'Sitecore.Logging.Client.12.0.0' is not found on source 'sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages'.
```

Comment: It has not moved - check https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/sitecore-public-nuget-feed-faq.html   And for your issue: which Nuget version are you using?

Comment: @Gatogordo Nuget version is 4.9.3.5777

Comment: Try upgrading that to 5.4.0

Comment: updated but now 
 Error  https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/: Package 'Sitecore.NVelocity.9.0.0' is not found on source 'https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/'.

      https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/: Package 'Sitecore.Zip.12.0.0' is not found on source 'https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/'.

https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/: Package 'Sitecore.Logging.Client.12.0.0' is not found on source 'https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/'.